# jQuery Store each value as a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I'm looping through each `select` with the class `specialMenuCat` and grabbing its value.

I'm using `console.log()` which shows the correct value but I'm not sure how to store this as a variable to use later.

```
<select class="specialMenuCat" name="menuCategory[]">
    <option value="apples">Apples</option>
    <option value="oranges">Oranges</option>
    <option value="peach">Peach</option>
    <option value="banana">Banana</option>
</select>


$('select.specialMenuCat').change(function(){   
    $('select.specialMenuCat').each(function(){
        var catVal = $(this).val();
        console.log(catVal);
    });
});
```

An example of the console log is;

```
apples (5)
oranges (4)
peach (5)
banana (5)
```

I tried setting the vars first and then incrementing them but it didn't work. My attempt;

```
$('select.specialMenuCat').change(function(){
    var apples = 0;
    $('select.specialMenuCat').each(function(apples){
        var catVal = $(this).val();
        if(catVal == apples) { apples++; }
        console.log(catVal);
    });
});
```

Comment: You can build an object with each fruit as a property of the object and the value as the count. That said, where are the fruit names coming from? The examples don't show them. It may also be beneficial if you could show the related HTML

Comment: On your second attempt your scope is in the function for the change event. If you move the definition outside into the global scope then you can use it across your code.

Comment: I thought it was clear from jQuery I'll add some html to the question now.

Comment: Just declare `var apples = 0;` above `$('select.specialMenuCat')`

Answer (score 0):

the apples variable is inside your change function, so it won't exist outside your change function. This should work:

```
var apples = 0;

$('select.specialMenuCat').change(function(){
    apples = 0; //reset, because you will start a new count
    $('select.specialMenuCat').each(function(item){
        var catVal = $(this).val();
        if(catVal == "apples") { apples++; }
        console.log(catVal);
    });
});

function SomeOtherEvent(){
    console.log(apples);
}
```

Comment: This looks like it will work thanks! Just update your answer the apples in the if statement isn't a string, in case others look at the question.

Comment: Good call - changed it

Comment: why SomeOtherEvent() ?

Comment: @dhaker The original question states "I'm not sure how to store this as a variable to use later." This indicates that the value needs to be saved even after the change event has finished. Logging the variable in another unrelated function shows that the value saved in the variable can be called from another function at any time

Answer (score 0):

initialize `apple variable` outside the onchange scope

because every time its re-initialize thats why value not increase

```
var apple = 0;
```

```js
var apple = 0;
$('select.specialMenuCat').change(function() {

  $('select.specialMenuCat').each(function() {
    var catVal = $(this).val();
    if (catVal == "apples") {
      apple++;
    }
    console.log(catVal);
  });
  console.log(apple);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="specialMenuCat" name="menuCategory[]">
  <option value="apples">Apples</option>
  <option value="oranges">Oranges</option>
  <option value="peach">Peach</option>
  <option value="banana">Banana</option>
</select>
```

Comment: We need to reset the apple variable after on the `change`, else the user can change the selection it will just add the number twice e.g. instead of 4 then 5 apples you have 9.

Answer (score 0):

Declare an object and push value into it every change by increment in its occurrence

in result you can get the value by accessing the property name by example number of apples the should be like `result['apple']`

See belwon snippet :

```js
$('select.specialMenuCat').change(function(){   
    $(".as-console").html("");
    
    result = {};
    $('select.specialMenuCat').each(function(){
        
        if(!this.value) return;
        
        val = result[this.value];
        
        result[this.value] = typeof(val)== 'undefined' ? 1 : ++val;
        
        
    });
    
    
    console.log(result);
    
    
    
    for (var prop in result) {
      if (result.hasOwnProperty(prop)) { 
        console.log("number of "+ prop + " is: " + result[prop])
      }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="specialMenuCat" name="menuCategory[]">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="apples">Apples</option>
    <option value="oranges">Oranges</option>
    <option value="peach">Peach</option>
    <option value="banana">Banana</option>
</select>

<select class="specialMenuCat" name="menuCategory[]">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="apples">Apples</option>
    <option value="oranges">Oranges</option>
    <option value="peach">Peach</option>
    <option value="banana">Banana</option>
</select>

<select class="specialMenuCat" name="menuCategory[]">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="apples">Apples</option>
    <option value="oranges">Oranges</option>
    <option value="peach">Peach</option>
    <option value="banana">Banana</option>
</select>

<select class="specialMenuCat" name="menuCategory[]">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="apples">Apples</option>
    <option value="oranges">Oranges</option>
    <option value="peach">Peach</option>
    <option value="banana">Banana</option>
</select>

<select class="specialMenuCat" name="menuCategory[]">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="apples">Apples</option>
    <option value="oranges">Oranges</option>>
    <option value="date">Dates</option>
</select>

<select class="specialMenuCat" name="menuCategory[]">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="melon">Melon</option>
    <option value="oranges">Oranges</option>>
    <option value="date">Dates</option>
</select>
```

Comment: does it help ? :)

Answer (score 0):

In the following Demo:

1. As suggested by Mr. McCrossan, create an Object Literal that has the fruit variables stored within. Keep your variables outside a function if you plan to increment/decrement the values. Referencing a value outside a function will create a closure which in turn causes a value to exist past the runtime of the function and thereby insuring a growing/shrinking value to build upon.
2. Register the `select.fruit` to the 'change' event
3. Get the value of the changed select with either `this` or `event.target` (in this Demo `this` is used).
4. Run the value through a `switch()` (I picked switch because it illustrates intentions very well).
5. On each matching `case` the value of the fruit property is incremented in the F Object as well as the corresponding `output`.

### Demo

**Details commented in Demo**

```js
/* Object literal stores each value 
|| Note it is outside of a function
*/
var F = {
  apples: 0,
  oranges: 0,
  peaches: 0,
  bananas: 0
};

// Any change events that happen on a .fruit, callback runs
$('.fruit').on('change', fruitCount);

// This callback passes the Event Object (not used in this Demo)
function fruitCount(e) {

  // "this" is the <select> currently changed
  var currentPick = this.value;
  switch (currentPick) {

    /* if the value of "this" is "apples"...
    || increment the 'apples' property of the F Object
    || and then increment the value of output#A
    || But if it isn't apples fall onto the next case
    */ // Same applies to the other fruits
    case 'apples':
      F.apples++;
      $('#A').val(F.apples);
      break;
    case 'oranges':
      F.oranges++;
      $('#O').val(F.oranges);
      break;
    case 'peaches':
      F.peaches++;
      $('#P').val(F.peaches);
      break;
    case 'bananas':
      F.bananas++;
      $('#B').val(F.bananas);
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

```css
select,
label,
output {
  font: inherit;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 8ch
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Fruit-O-Rama</legend>
  <label>Apples: </label><output id='A'></output><br>
  <label>Oranges: </label><output id='O'></output><br>
  <label>Peaches: </label><output id='P'></output><br>
  <label>Bananas: </label><output id='B'></output><br>
</fieldset>
<select class="fruit" name="menu0[]">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="apples">Apples</option>
  <option value="oranges">Oranges</option>
  <option value="peaches">Peaches</option>
  <option value="bananas">Bananas</option>
</select>
<br>
<select class="fruit" name="menu1[]">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="apples">Apples</option>
  <option value="oranges">Oranges</option>
  <option value="peaches">Peaches</option>
  <option value="bananas">Bananas</option>
</select>
<br>
<select class="fruit" name="menu2[]">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="apples">Apples</option>
  <option value="oranges">Oranges</option>
  <option value="peaches">Peaches</option>
  <option value="bananas">Bananas</option>
</select>
<br>
<select class="fruit" name="menu3[]">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="apples">Apples</option>
  <option value="oranges">Oranges</option>
  <option value="peaches">Peaches</option>
  <option value="bananas">Bananas</option>
</select>
<br>
<select class="fruit" name="menu4[]">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="apples">Apples</option>
  <option value="oranges">Oranges</option>
  <option value="peaches">Peaches</option>
  <option value="bananas">Bananas</option>
</select>
<br>
<select class="fruit" name="menu5[]">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="apples">Apples</option>
  <option value="oranges">Oranges</option>
  <option value="peaches">Peaches</option>
  <option value="bananas">Bananas</option>
</select>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```